# not able to serialize java object containing ArrayList using xstream library in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, serialization, xstream

using the xstream library to serialize an object in Android into XML.  however it is not working.  The object shown here contains an ArrayList as a member.  It is impossible to serialize objects like this with xstream?  or is there some way to make this work?

http://x-stream.github.io/

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
str.add("test xml string one");
str.add("test xml string two");
str.add("test xml string three");

ExampleObject testObj = new ExampleObject(str); 

XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());

String xmlStr = xstream.toXML(testObj);

textView.setText(xmlStr);

} // onCreate

public class ExampleObject {

ArrayList<String> memberList;

 public ExampleObject(ArrayList<String> list) {
     memberList = list;
 }

} // ExampleObject

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you implement the Serial UID?

Here is why it may not be functioning properly:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345678;
```

The class Serializable decodes written Objects by using the UID mentioned above. Without this number, the class will not be able to decode the object. I have also heard that if you significantly modify the class, then try to read back the data, the operation will fail.

Comment: ok, i added this line and made the class implement Serializable, and it will eventually print out the string, but it is COMICALLY SLOW,  have to wait for up to 20 seconds